# Google Now Launcher doesn't list installed apps on MIUI8

Tags: launcher, google-now, miui

I am using MIUI8 on my Mi4i. I have installed Google Now launcher, but the app drawer does not show the list of apps. See the picture:

[image]

But searching from the search bar in home screen returns matched apps:

[image]

Oddly, the search bar in app drawer doesn't show any result:

[image]

Can you tell me a solution? I have tried wiping the cache from recovery mode but it didn't work.

Current android version: 5.0.2 (LRX22G)
MIUI version: MIUI 8 Global 6.8.18 Beta
Google App and Google Now Launcher are up to date.

Comment: Google Now Launcher is not being updated from a very long time. It was lastly updated on October 2015. I think it is not compatible with the latest version of Android.

Comment: @MANI OMG, yeah. last update was on 15 oct, 2015. Shame!

Comment: You can try Nova Launcher which is a nice replacement for Google Now Launcher. It gives you the same UI experience with lots of customizations.

Comment: Same problem on MIUI8 on Redmi Note 3

Comment: I had exactly the same problem on the same system and this solution helped (http://c.mi.com/thread-27432-1-0.html):

1) Uninstall Google Now Launcher.
2) Open Play Store and install Google Now Launcher. Do NOT open the app after it is installed!
3) Go to Settings > Permissions; turn on "Autostart" permission for Google Now Launcher.
4) Go to Settings > Dual apps; enable dual support for Google Now Launcher.
5) Go to Settings > Home screen; select Google Now Launcher as the default lanucher.